# I need to iterate over a JSON array - not sure how to do it - have searched but still can't get a clue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON array I'm getting from php:

```
"{\"GUINNESS\":[\"Food\",\"Gifting\",\"Merchandise\"]}"
```

In Jquery I have -

```
$.getJSON("menu_processing.php",function(json) {
  $.each(json,function(index,val) {
 $("ul.navlist").append('<li id="'+index+'" class="list">'+val+'</li>');    
    });  

});
```

I want to get Guiness as the top level, and process the nested array as a sublevel  -

I was thinking something  like:

```
$.each(json,function(index,val) {
    // print the top level 
    $.each(json,function(key,val) {
        // print the sub level
});});
```

But I still can't figure out how to about this in jquery - any help or pointers much appreciated.  I tried searching for something here but nothing even gives me a clue about how to go about this.  Am I even on the right track in jquery?

Answer (score 3):

`$.getJSON` parses the JSON for you. To get the `GUINNESS` property - the array - of the object, you can use the normal [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators):

```
$.getJSON("menu_processing.php",function(json) {
    var ul = $("ul.navlist");
    $.each(json.GUINNESS, function(i, val) {
//             ^^^^^^^^^
        ul.append('<li class="list">'+val+'</li>');    
    });
});
```

If you don't know the property names in the top object (like `"GUINESS"`), you can use the double each (or a much simpler for-loop) as you guessed correct:

```
$.getJSON("menu_processing.php",function(json) {
    var ul = $("ul.navlist");
    $.each(json, function(name, val) {
        // name === "GUINNESS"
        // val is the array
        $.each(val, function(name, subval) {
            ul.append('<li class="list">'+subval+'</li>');    
    });
});
```

The same with normal loop syntax:

```
// …
    for (var name in json) {
        var val = json[name];
        for (var i=0; i<val.length; i++) {
            var subval = val[i];
            // do something
        }
    }
// …
```

Comment: I still don't follow you, how do I go about that - json.object or json.key? - from what I understand you're saying double each loop is not necessary.

Comment: Arggh!  I'm getting a type a is null and type a is undefined error.  I'm basicaly trying to populate a dynamic navigation menu based on the result set from a database.  Guinness is one of the top level options and the only one that has a sublevel.

Comment: I don't know what your `a` is, but this seems to come from your DOM creation code which you didn't present us.

Answer (score 1):

You want to iterate over the json.GUINESS property, which is an array, rather than json, which is an object after being parsed by the .getJSON method:

```
$.each(json.GUINESS, function (index, val) {
    $('ul.navlist').append('<li id="' + index + '" class="list">' + val + '</li>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reassign the JSON variable as the `GUINNESS` value;

```
$.getJSON("menu_processing.php",function(json) {
    json = json.GUINNESS
    $.each(json,function(index,val) {
        $("ul.navlist").append('<li id="'+index+'" class="list">'+val+'</li>');    
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$.each(json, function() {
    // You access the values using this.somearraykey
    if(isArray(this.somearraykey)){ // If you need to check if it is a multidimentional array
        $items = [];

        // More iterating
        $.each(this.somevalue, function(){
            // Push the values into some structure
            $items.push('<li id="' + this.whatever + '">' + this.somevalue + ' ' + this.someothervalue'</li>');
        });

        $joined = '<ul>' + $items.join('') + '</ul>';
    } else{
        $joined  = '';
    }

    $newitem = [];
    $newitem.push('<li>' + this.someotherarraykey + $joined + '</li>'); // push, push.. 
    $('#placeholderOrWhatever').html('<ul>' + $newitem.join('') + '</ul>');
});
```

The thing you should focus on (at least so far as I've come) is `.push` (array push) and `.join`

**Edit:** You of course need this function to make it work:

```
function isArray(what) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(what) === '[object Array]';
}
```